# Creating a model in Laravel causes database error

Tags: laravel, heroku, eloquent

I am working on a laravel code on my personal computer with no attachment to a database. I am creating the migrations and other things and then pushing the code to heroku where I run the migrations. I have built a few code bases with postgres databases this way.

For some reason, after I followed [this tutorial](https://thewebtier.com/laravel/understanding-roles-permissions-laravel/) to create my own user system with roles and permissions, I cannot create a model or controller after the initial migration is run.

This is the error that I get.

```
In Connection.php line 664:

Database hosts array is empty. (SQL: select * from "permissions")  


In ConnectionFactory.php line 203:

Database hosts array is empty.
```

My config -> Database and .env files are configured as they always are, but I want to emphasize that this shouldn't matter as I am not connected to a database.  I am not running a migration, I am simply trying to create a model or a controller.

I have never had this problem before and it is killing me on a time sensitive issue.

Comment: You can use sqlite with the :memory database option on dev box.

Answer (score 0):

Your database configuration is missing. check the files `config/database.php` and `.env`.

```
'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1')
```

Comment: I tried all of that. I am just trying to create a new model. To my knowledge, there is no reason to connect to a database prior to a migration. There is something else wrong here.

Comment: @JoshuaFoxworth even if the database is not really needed, it's still part of the bootstrapping process of laravel and is required for migration initialization.

Comment: If I do heroku run php artisan make:model Message -m, it works. Do I need to run some sort of postgres on my machine when I create the model?

Comment: A better solution would be to use SQLite with `:memory` option. so nothing is saved. in anycase, have you tried to create the model without the `-m` flag ?